# Parallel running multiple test files multiple times using pytest+selenuim

Tags: python, pytest

So, I have the .json file that basically looks like this:

```
{
    "devices": [
        {
            "model" : "model_name",
            "device name" : "name",
            "address" : "http://adrress.local/",
            "role" : "device's role"
        },
    ...
```

What I need is to run all the test files, using the given .json file.
For each device run every test file in parallel.
Let's say I have 3 devices and 3 test files.
How to run 9 pytest instances for this? It should look like this:

```
device1 test_1.py PASSED
device2 test_1.py PASSED
device1 test_2.py PASSED
device3 test_1.py PASSED
```

I'm new in python and pytest, so the only idea I have for now is to create a shell script what will be running needed pytest commands in cycle.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at pytest-xdist: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/

Comment: yep, I think I already solved my problem) by using @pytest.mark.parametrize() and xdist)